# Разложить XML в HashMap

Tags: spring, xml, spring-boot

В приложение на Spring Boot прилетает строка с XML следующего формата:

```
<root>
  <key1>value1</key1>
  <key2>value2</key2>
</root>
```

Заранее неизвестно, какие будут ключи. Как можно разложить подобную структуру в HashMap?

Comment: см.https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml  и `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper`. Аннотацию поставишь на поле `HashMap root`

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!